# multiple connections in CodeIgniter are very slow - how to speed up

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3, here is the code in question:

```
//now transfer data - this only works for very small to medium tables
$all = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$sourceServer['database'].'`.`'.$table.'`';
if($data = $this->source->cnx->query($all)){
    $sqls = [];
    foreach($data->result_array() as $v){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$targetServer['database'] . '`.`' . $targetTable . '` SET ';
        foreach($v as $o => $w){
            $sql .= "\n\t`" . $o . '`=' .
                (is_null($w) ? '' : "'") .
                (is_null($w) ? 'NULL' : str_replace("'", "\\'", $w)) .
                (is_null($w) ? '' : "'") . ',';
        }
        $sqls[] = rtrim($sql, ',');
    }
    foreach($sqls as $sql){
        $this->target->cnx->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Note that `$this->target->cnx..` and `$this->source->cnx..` are instantiated  CI connections but could well be on two different physical servers on a network.

Also, both connections are open the entire time of processing since I may well want to perform other cross-network operations later (I could close `$this->source->cnx` after I got the data but might have to open it again).

I find this is very slow; how can I speed it up?

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is **extremely dangerous** because that is **not** the correct way to escape SQL values.

Comment: Hint: Assemble conditions into an `array` and `implode`. Don't concatenate to a string and trim off the trailing character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Replace your multiple insert using foreach into batch insert

  foreach($sqls as $sql){
          $this->target->cnx->query($sql);
      }
  //replace it with

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
note data is array of array [[],[],[]...[]]
or form query like this

INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'),  ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code in order to get one insert string like

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,....coln) VALUES
(val11,....val1n),
....
(valn1,....valnn);
```

Then execute it in one query() call.

Problem is not Codeigniter but too much overhead in performing n INSERT compared to perform one INSERT of N rows.